# Text Block and button blocking by image after add background image

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I am new to uwp visual studio and I trying to set a background image, but it will cover the button and the text block after I add the background image. How should I make the button and text block display on top the background image?

below are the code I doing

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Assets/starsky.png"/>
    
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="ResultTextBlock"/>
        <Button Content="Get Weather" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
    
</Grid>
```

below are the image before and after I add background image

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPGAa.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir19R.png)

Comment: Are you sure that's the **exact** XAML you used? Because it works perfectly for me -- elements are added in lexical order, so the `StackPanel` will be above the `Image`. If you reverse the order of them, then you will not see the `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can get this working.

One of the easiest way you can do this is to set the `Canvas.ZIndex` attribute of the `StackPanel`. By default, the ZIndex of the elements is 0 so every element is on the same *level*, due to which the image hides the `StackPanel`. (More info on [ZIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.zindexproperty?view=winrt-19041))

**Updated XAML :**

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Assets/starsky.png"/>
    <StackPanel Canvas.ZIndex="1" >
        <TextBlock Name="ResultTextBlock"/>
        <Button Content="Get Weather" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The `Canvas.ZIndex` property is only used by the `Canvas` control, not the `Grid` control. Also, the default value is documented as `-1` :).

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/qifssWk.png - I added the Canvas.ZIndex property from the properties panel (seems to be available for the `StackPanel`), on removing the value from the attribute of the `StackPanel` the properties panel is showing it as 0..

Comment: You can attach it anywhere, but only `Canvas` understands it. You are correct though it defaults to zero. I will suggest an update to the docs. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)